# How to check JsonAraay is null or not?

Tags: java, json, arrays

I would like to check JsonArray **existTeamMemberships** is null or not? I would like to use IF statement next to this code to check JsonArray has null or not?How could check this?

```
  JsonArray existTeamMemberships = (JsonArray) userQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("TeamMemberships");
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to  ask whether Array is Blank???

Comment: yes how could check the JSON array elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(existTeamMemberships!=null){
//code
}
```

Simple.